# SharePoint Online : Create New Group in Term Set

Tags: sharepoint-online, term-store

Sorry maybe this is such a dummy question.

I want to try managing term store in sharepoint online. I got this tutorial in Office Support to create new group in term store

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-up-a-new-group-for-term-sets-2b6d2e1b-6b1f-43db-80dc-51ca777b3d17?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

It said that to create new group I should right-click or point to taxonomy header and there will be an arrow and option to create New Group. But I can't find it in my sharepoint online. I already tried to point my cursor into taxonomy header or also right click the taxonomy header, but there is no option to create new group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so i found the answer by myself. I need to add my account in **Term Store Administrators**, before I can manage the term store.

Thanks for this link http://sharepointmaven.com/create-metadata-sharepoint/